# Read subcollection from Firestore flutter

Tags: list, flutter, collections, google-cloud-firestore

How to read subcollection from flutter firestore. I am using cloud_firestore. I am successfully adding data into firestore but couldn't retrieve it(tried and failed).

```
    FirebaseUser user=await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    uid=user.uid;
    return user.uid;
  }
  Future addSpend(Spend spend) {
    String date=DateFormat('MM-yyyy').format(spend.date);
    print("BLB DB $date");
    return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transactionHandler) {
      return Firestore.instance
          .collection("Spends")
          .document(uid).collection(date).document()
          .setData(spend.toJson());
    });
  }
```

I tried to read all that subcollections into list of objects. But failed.

```
//    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("Spends").document(Repository.uid).collection("10-2019").getDocuments();
//    print("BLB ${querySnapshot.documentChanges}");
//    var list = querySnapshot.documents;
//    return list;


//   List<DocumentSnapshot> templist;
//   List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = new List();
//    var path=Firestore.instance.collection("Spends").document(uid).collection("10-2019");
//
//    var collectionSnapshot=await path.getDocuments();
//    print("BLB collection ${collectionSnapshot}");
//   templist = collectionSnapshot.documents;
//   print("BLB templist ${templist.length}");
//   list = templist.map((DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot){
//     return docSnapshot.data;
//   }).toList();
//
//   return list;
   var doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('Spends').reference();
   doc.getDocuments().then((res){
     print("BLB DB ${res.documentChanges.length}");
   }).catchError((e){
     print("BLB DB error $e");
   });

//   doc.then((document){
//     print("BLB DB ${document.exists}");
//   }).catchError((e){
//     print("BLB DB error $e");
//   });
  }
```

Model class

```
  Spend();
  String id,amount; String title; String category; DateTime date; String description;

  Spend.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : id = snapshot.documentID,
        amount = snapshot['amount'],
        category = snapshot['category'],
        date = snapshot['date'],
        title = snapshot['title'],
        description = snapshot['description'];

  toJson(){
    return {
      "amount":amount,
      "category":category,
      "date":date,
      "description":description,
      "title":title

    };
  }
}
```

[image: Firebase database]
[image: Firebase DB conti..]

Can someone through some light on me. I want to read that subcollection into list. I am using cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4.

Comment: Are u getting error ? `Firestore.instance.collection(...).document(uid).collection(...)` This code should work. In my flutter app, i am using firebase too, and i am successfully bring data with that code `QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('user_groups').document(user.userId).collection('groups').getDocuments()`

Comment: No error ``` print(querySnapshot.documents.length);``` but giving 0 as output.

Answer (score 6):

You just want to

```
Firestore.collection("collection/documentid/subcollectionname').getdocuments
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reasons for this behaviour. One can be that you [query for documents that don’t exist](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents).

Also take into consideration [Firestore documentation for Listing subcollections of a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

Taking this into account maybe trying to use this snippet will resolve your issue:

```
var spendsRef = await Firestore.instance.document('Spends/YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID');
spendsRed.getCollections() => then(collections => {
    collections.forEach(collection => {
    console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection_id);
 });
});
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: I have added database screen shots. Can you check it. Your code giving errors(couldn't compile).

Comment: In your first screenshot the message "This document does not exist and will not appear in queries or snapshots" is confirming my first hypothesis. You are trying to query for a document that doesn't exist. Please check [Non-existent ancestor documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents)

Comment: Thanks bro. Any idea to add subcollections in firestore?

Comment: [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) is the official documentation. [This](https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190306/12123.html) may be helpful too. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Since my answer was correct I would kindly suggest to approve it in order to give visibility to other users.

Comment: I migrated to realtime database. Not using firestore out of frustration.